# Sitecore system data types, are we expected to use these

Tags: types, sitecore

I noticed when creating fields for a template a number of data types under System, such as DataSource, Rendering DataSource and so on.  Can these be used in our field types and is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use them as data types in your own fields defined on a template. You are using some of these already without [maybe] realizing, e.g. datasource when adding renderings.

There is not much documentation on the field types. There are some legacy documentation on the old [SDN site](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Media/Referencing%20Binary%20Items/Field%20Types.aspx), the [Data Definition Reference](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Data%20Definition%20Reference.aspx) (see section 4.2) for Sitecore 7 and updates in some blog posts such as [this on Sitecore 7](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-7-new-field-types) or this [post on Field Type Overview](http://www.mtelligent.com/home/2014/8/29/sitecore-field-type-overview-reference.html). This should cover most of them, I can't recall if there were any new fields added in Sitecoore 8, but you may need to investigate them with Reflector or dotPeek yourself.

Just bear in mind that the fields may not be the most user friendly for your content authors, and they may not be directly editable in the Experience Editor (although you culd use Edit Frames).